# Understanding clientSecret in FacebookLogin plugin

Tags: facebook-authentication, flutter

In the [flutter_facebook_connect](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/flutter_facebook_connect/0.0.3/) documentation, we need to set two properties when signing in appId and clientSecret

```
new FacebookLoginButton(
          appId: '<APP_ID>',
          clientSecret: '<CLIENT_SECRET>',
          scope: [FacebookAuthScope.publicProfile],
          onConnect: (api, token) {
           ...
          }),
```

I am trying to understand what are these properties. I understand that I need to replace **appId** value with my application ID, but what exactly is the clientSecret and how to make use of it?

Comment: it´s clientSecret, not clientServer. take a look at your app settings to find it.

Comment: It was a typo. Can you please help me locating it in firebase? and what is it exactly ?

Comment: again, please open the app settings on facebook, it is not hard to find. you must have created the app already, if you got the app id. it is not at all related to firebase.

Comment: I get how to work it around now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If this can help anyone here I will answer the question.

1. Go to [Facebook developer dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/).
2. Choose the application you working on or create the new one.

   - The link will be like

     > https://developers.facebook.com/apps/`app_id_here`/dashboard/
3. From the left side menu (English .. etc) or right side (Arabic .. etc).
4. Click on `Settings` and then choose from sub menu `Basic`.
5. Now you will see `App ID` and `App Secret`.
6. You have to copy `App ID` and for `App Secret` click on Show button and then type your Facebook account password, then you will see the `App Secret`, just copy and paste.

Here's screenshot maybe help more.
[image: Hint screenshot for the answer]

And Hola you got it. Hope it can help anyone looking for answer in this matter.